# trying to obtain mysql data into two while loops to json_output

Tags: php, mysql, json, while-loop

hi i am trying to make two while loop in order to be able to properly categorize the data i have stored in a database and then json_output it

my code is the following:

```
//verifica qual é o elemento pai
$sql1 = 'SELECT DISTINCT itempt_dim 
        FROM dim 
        WHERE id_dim = (
                        SELECT DISTINCT iddimblg_rdim 
                        FROM rdim 
                        WHERE iddimblg_rdim NOT IN (
                                                    SELECT iddim_rdim 
                                                    FROM rdim
                                                    )
                    )';

$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {

    $elem_pai = $row['itempt_dim'] ;

    $grupo = [
      'name' => $elem_pai,
      'color' => $cor_alea,
      'size' => 1,
      'children' => $marcas[]
    ];

    //query para obter os elementos filhos
    $sql2 = "SELECT itempt_dim 
            FROM dim 
            WHERE id_dim = ANY (
                                SELECT DISTINCT iddim_rdim 
                                FROM rdim 
                                WHERE iddimblg_rdim = (
                                                        SELECT id_dim 
                                                        FROM dim 
                                                        WHERE itempt_dim = ". "'" . $elem_pai . "'" ."
                                                        )
                            )";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

    //verifica os elementos filhos
    $marcas = [];

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

      $marcas = [
        'name' => $row['itempt_dim'],
        'color' => $cor_alea,
        'size' => 1
      ];

    }

  }

  print_r(json_encode($grupo));
```

the thing is that i keep getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in
>   C:\wamp64\www\algoritmo_pdi\sunburst.php on line 25

can someone help me ? thanks in advance!

Comment: And which is line 25 please?

Comment: While not related to the error, you're overwriting `$marcas` in your while loop. You need to assign the results to `$marcas[]`

Comment: line 25 is: "'name' => $elem_pai,"

Comment: @aynber the thing is that i dont want the output to be [{OUTPUT}] i want it to be just {OUTPUT}

Comment: You'll also want to move `$grupo` to below your second while loop, since `$marcas` won't be created/populated until after that loop.

Comment: Gotcha. The `$marcas` is fine, then. You'll still want to move the `$grupo` creation to below that while loop so that the variable is actually created

Answer (score 2):

I think this is wrong:

```
'children' => $marcas[]
```

And this overwrite on each loop

```
 $marcas = [
    'name' => $row['itempt_dim'],
    'color' => $cor_alea,
    'size' => 1
  ];
```

So, corrected code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {

    $elem_pai = $row['itempt_dim'] ;

    $grupo = [
      'name' => $elem_pai,
      'color' => $cor_alea,
      'size' => 1,
      'children' => $marcas
    ];

    //query para obter os elementos filhos
    $sql2 = "SELECT itempt_dim FROM dim WHERE id_dim = ANY (SELECT DISTINCT iddim_rdim FROM rdim WHERE iddimblg_rdim = (SELECT id_dim FROM dim WHERE itempt_dim = ". "'" . $elem_pai . "'" ."))";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

    //verifica os elementos filhos
    $marcas = [];

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {

      $marcas[] = [
        'name' => $row['itempt_dim'],
        'color' => $cor_alea,
        'size' => 1
      ];

    }
}
```

Comment: Woops! Except that `//verifica os elementos filhos
    $marcas = [];` need to go above `$groupo = ....` or `$marcus will not yet exist when you try and us it